# I am getting unwanted null with my json output in json-api wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, web-services

I am new in wordpress and using Json-Api in wordpress for web-services, and I have create my own service in  `json-api/controllers/core.php` file my function is:

```
<?php
public function get_blogs(){
global $json_api;
$categories = $json_api->introspector->get_categories($args);
echo  "[";
foreach($categories as $cat){
if($cat->id == "5432"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5433"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5439"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5444"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5440"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5438"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5430"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
 if($cat->id == "5435"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5436"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5434"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5441"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5445"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5431"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5437"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "203"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}".",";
}
if($cat->id == "5442"){
 $catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
 echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
  $catnow = json_encode($catPost);
  echo $catnow;
  echo "}".",";
  }
  if($cat->id == "5447"){
  $catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
  echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
  $catnow = json_encode($catPost);
  echo $catnow;
  echo "}".",";
  }
  if($cat->id == "530"){
  $catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
  echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
  $catnow = json_encode($catPost);
  echo $catnow;
   echo "}".",";
  }
  if($cat->id == "5443"){
  $catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
  echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
  $catnow = json_encode($catPost,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  echo $catnow;
  echo "}".",";
  }
if($cat->id == "5448"){
$catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
echo "{"."\"category_title\":\"$cat->title\"".",\"category_id\":\"$cat->id\"".",\"posts\":";
$catnow = json_encode($catPost);
echo $catnow;
echo "}";
}

}
echo  "]";
  }
```

After that when I am getting its output as I want ,one null is extra added in Json after finish my Json output `"]null"` in last, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems highly likely there is another file being run after the one you've posted, that is responsible for echoing that `null`. It is worth looking into this.

Having said that, rather than trying to format your own JSON output, you're probably better creating data objects, and then encoding them with `json_encode()`.

So, for instance, to take the last block of your code, it would look like

```
if($cat->id == "5448"){
    $catPost = get_posts('cat="$cat->id"&posts_per_page=4');
    echo json_encode(array(
      "category_title" => $cat->title,
      "category_id" => $cat->id,
      "posts" => $catPost
    ));
}
```

If the entire thing is written in this form, it should get rid of any formatting errors.